# Deserializing Json with RestSharp to get properties

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am having a problem extracting the "Id" property from the following JSON result using RestSharp: 
****Here is the JSON***:

```
{

  "odata.metadata":"Api/v1/$metadata#Folders","odata.count":"1","value":
  [

    {

      "odata.id":"/Api/v1/Folders('c8644e97b4ca4353b5bd74a0cc37588214')","Presentations@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"/Api/v1/Folders('c8644e97b4ca4353b5bd74a0cc37588214')/Presentations","#UpdatePermissions":
      {

        "target":"Api/v1/Folders('c8644e97b4ca4353b5bd74a0cc37588214')/UpdatePermissions"

      }
      ,"Id":"c8644e97b4ca4353b5bd74a0cc37588214","Name":"2013-AAFGSW","Owner":"John Doe","Description":"EPIDEM 150.03, Summer 2013","CreationDate":"2014-06-09T22:00:43","LastModified":"2014-06-09T22:00:43","ParentFolderId":"2f5469c7bdf641878c8baf2988ceeb9a14","Recycled":false,"Type":"Folder"

    }

  ]

}
```

***Here are my classes that I am using:***

```
public class Value
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModified { get; set; }
    public string ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    public bool Recycled { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class FolderRoot <T>
{

    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}
```

***Here is the request code:***

```
                var BuildFolderIdRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                BuildFolderIdRequest.Resource = string.Format("Folders?$filter=Name eq '{0}'",x.event_locator);
                BuildFolderIdRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                BuildFolderIdRequest.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
                BuildFolderIdRequest.AddHeader("apikey", ApiKey);
    var Fold = MediasiteClient.Execute<FolderRoot<Value>>(BuildFolderIdRequest);
                Console.WriteLine("The folder content is {0}", Fold.Content);
                Console.WriteLine("The folder Id is {0}", Fold.Data.????);
                Console.ReadKey();
```

The problem is trying to extract the "Id" -- as I can't do it with "Fold.Data.Id" , instead i just get "Fold.Data.value" as my only option...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using MediaSite's new v7 REST API.  Try the following just before executing your request:

```
BuildFolderIdRequest.RootElement = "value";
```

If you look at the raw JSON results you were already receiving with `Fold.Content` you should see that the results you want are under the node called `value`.  Without that mapping, deserialization might not work.  Best of luck.

Comment: Yes thanks for your response. Using value did indeed work -- as I didn't realize the folder was returning a list...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select an element of your list before you can get an ID from it,
like

```
        Fold.Data[0].Id
```

Does that work? I am not overly familiar with de-serialization, but that's what it looks like to me.

Is the type of "Folder.Data.value" a list?

Comment: Thanks  -- Unfortunately that doesn't work as I am trying to extract the string value of "Id" in the "Value" class.

Comment: Hi -- Yes a slight variation of your solution worked ! I am able to get it when I put `Fold.Data.value[0].Id`--- Much appreciated...